# How can we extract data from java/android mobile application, which crawler can be used for data extraction from mobile app?sn

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler

Best mobile app crawler to be used for extracting data from like we do for websites using scrappy

Comment: Do you want to crawl playstore for app meta details/reviews? or android app deeplinks?

Comment: @VikashRathee: Hi, I need to extract data from mobile apps details/reviews like from eCommerce mobile apps about their products.